# how to use kubectl command with flag --selector?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a question about kubectl command with flag --selector. In help menu it says,

```
-l, --selector="": Selector (label query) to filter on
```

how ever it does't work as i expect, 
for example, i want to get RC who have selector like

```
    "spec": {
    "replicas": 2,
    "selector": {
        "app": "tas-core"
    },
```

when i give command

```
kubectl get pod --selector="app:tas-core"
```

system report: the provided selector "app:tas-core" is not valid: unable to parse requirement: label key: invalid value 'app:tas-core', Details: must match regex [a-z0-9?(.a-z0-9?)* / ] a-z0-9?

after i check the regexp

```
[[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)* / ] [a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?
```

i still can't find any string which can pass the regexp!
i gave,

```
kubectl get rc -l app/tas-core
```

nothing has been returned.
How could i use it?

I have also another question, how to filter all pods which with label like

```
"labels": {
  "app": "tas-core"
}
```

?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try

```
kubectl get pods --selector=app=tas-core
```

as in http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-cheatsheet/

Comment: great thanks, it works! but how to explain regexp: 
[[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)* / ] [a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?
it doesn't make any sense with "app=tas-core" mode? is it a bug here?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any idea about this regexp, just start work on kubernetes.

Answer (score 14):

- To use one selector with kubectl command,apply the follwing command:
  `kubectl get po --selector name=value` where **name** is the selector name and **value** is the selector value.
- You can use rc, svc or deployments (any k8s resource) needed to be listed and also filtered with a selector.
- There is also an option to list or filter k8s resources with multiple selectors, just use the following command:
  `kubectl get all --selector name1=value1,name2=value2,name3=value3`

Comment: Right, as `kubectl get pods --help | grep "\--selector="` says: Selector (label query) to filter on, supports '=', '==', and '!='. (e.g. -l key1=value1,key2=value2)

Answer (score 2):

We should be able to query the pod name using label `selectors` and `jsonpath`

```
kubectl get pods -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=nginx" -o jsonpath={.items[0].metadata.name}
```